# output of inference section in niftynet run

Tags: niftynet

I can't seem to find where my inference models are, I have the .csv files and can see the loss but I can't find the label files or images themselves.
This is my inference section:

border = (44,44,44) 
output_interp_order = 0

By the documentation I should have my inference output in my output folder, which I believe is the model_dir written in the SYSTEM section which only has the following contents:
[model_dir contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JkEe.png)

Answer (score 0):

in the .ini file in the [INFERENCE] section there is the save_seg_dir="./output/" which create a folder in the model_dir (in [SYSTEM] section) when you run the net_segment inference -c file.

cf this config for example : https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/blob/dev/config/weighted_sample_regression.ini

Best regards